# Lagrange Multipliers have no solution

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

$f(x,y)=2x+y$ subject to constraint $x+y=m$.
$(2,1)=\lambda(1,1)$ but this does not satisfy $x+y=m$
So there are no solution?

Comment: It's difficult to make sense of your problem as it stands, please provide more context.

Comment: How to explain that max=2x+y subject to constraint x+y=m. Has no solution?

Comment: Subject to the constraint, $2x+y$ has neither a max nor a min.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, there are no solution. It is pretty obvious that $x+y = m$ represent a line in the plane and $2x+y$ is a nontrivial linear function on this line. It is impossible to have critical point.

What's more, just substitute $x+y=m$ into $2x+y$ give $m+x$, and $x$ can be anything........

Comment: Is this the same reason that max x+y s.t. x+y=m, x,y>0; m >0 doesn't have a simple solution?

Comment: Actually, in that case, the function is _the same_ as the constraint function.  Therefore, for every point on the line $ \ x + y \ = \ m \ $ , the function _has_ the value $ \ m \ . $  So there is no maximum or minimum (or the maximum and the minimum are the same value and apply everywhere on the line, or however you wish to describe this peculiar condition).

Answer (score 1):

Another way of saying what is at issue here: the Lagrange-multiplier method is intended to locate points on the curve, surface, etc. where the gradient vector $ \ \nabla f \ $ has the same direction as the gradient for the constraint function, $ \ \nabla g \ $ .  (Thus, one is *at least* a scalar multiple $ \ \lambda \ $ of the other, giving this technique its name.)

But in this problem as written, the normal vector to the line $ \ f(x,y) \ = \ 2x + y \ $ is *always* in a different direction from the normal vector to the line of the constraint function, $ \ x + y \ = \ m \ . $  So the method will not produce a solution.  [You wound up with the "equation" $ \ \langle 2, 1 \rangle \ = \ \lambda \ \langle 1, 1 \rangle \ . \ $ As they say: "not gonna happen"...]