# Solving lagrange multiplies

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

The problem is:

$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{max} & \quad ax+by \\
\text{subject to} & \quad x+y=m.
\end{align}
$$

The Lagrangian is:

$$L(x,y) = ax+by−λ(x+y−m).$$

And so far I have:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} & =a−λ=0, \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} & =b−λ=0.
\end{align}
$$

How to solve it from here?

Answer (score 1):

From the two equations you wrote at the end, you can see that $\lambda = a$ and $\lambda = b$. This means the problem can only be solved if $a=b$. In that case, the function you are minimizing is $ax+by=ax+ay=a(x+y)=a\cdot m$ constant (constant on the space where you are looking at).

This makes sense, since, if $a< b$ (a similar argument can be made for $a>b$), you can rewrite the function as $$ax+by = ax + by +ay - ay = a(x+y) + (b-a)y = am + (b-a)y.$$ Since you can now pick an arbitrary large value of $y$ and still have $x = m-y$ so that $x+y=m$, the function has no maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of saying this is that the Lagrange-multiplier method locates points on  "level curves" of the function that have a normal vector in the same direction as a normal vector to the "curve" represented by the constraint function.

In this problem, the function to be extremized is *linear*, $ \ f(x,y) \ = \ ax \ + \ by \ $ , as is the constraint function, $ \ g(x,y) \ = \ x \ + \ y \ - \ m \ $ .  The difficulty with this is that the normal to the line for the function $ \ f \ $ has slope $ \ + \frac{b}{a} \ $ for *any* of its level curves $ \ ax \ + \ by \ = \ C \ $ , but the constraint function  has a normal with slope $ \ +1 \ $ .  These slopes will *never* agree for $ \ a \ \neq \ b \ $ , so the method will *not* find a solution: there is no extremum value for $ \ C \ $ that can satisfy the constraint.  A geometrical interpretation is that **any** choice of $ \ C \ $ for the linear equation $ \ ax \ + \ by \ = \ C \ $ will produce a line that intersects $ \ x \ + \ y \ = \ m \ $ at a point, so there is no *unique* value of $ \ C \ $ that can serve as an extremum.

A different situation emerges for $ \ a \ = \ b \ $ .  Now the line $ \ ax \ + \ ay \ = \ C \ $ matches the constraint for $ \ \frac{C}{a} \ = \ m \ $ ; in fact, it matches it for *every* point on the line (the "level curve" and the constraint are *the same line*).  So there are an infinite number of values of $ \ x \ $ and $ \ y \ $ which satisfy the constraint, and there is only this *single* value of $ \ C \ $ that provides the "extremum".  Because there is only the one value, it is neither a maximum or a minimum (or this becomes an issue of semantics).

There is a discussion of a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/663021/lagrange-multipliers-have-no-solution/) .